# Удалить последние 2 предложения из файла

Tags: c, файлы

У меня есть текстовый файл, нужно переписать его содержимое в другой файл, но не учитывать последние 2 предложения. Не совсем понимаю, какой алгоритм решения и какие функции использовать( Концом предложения я считаю . ! или ? Возможно, установить указатель на конец файла, и двигаться назад, пока не дойду к третьему символу конца предложения? Как это реализовать?

Comment: снова  лабораторные  работы  ??

Comment: Возможно, есть функции типа seek

Comment: @Slavik они самые(

Comment: @Jezz проходили

Comment: @Jezz https://metanit.com/cpp/c/7.6.php

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего не будет слишком неприемлемо для производительности прочитать файл полностью 2 раза. В первый раз прочитай посимвольно весь файл и определи максимальное количество содержащихся в нём предложений. Далее реализуй копирование, подсчитывая сколько предложений уже скопировано. Остановись когда предложений *(N - 2)*, где *N* - количество предложений в исходном файле.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input_file, *output_file;
    int sentences_num = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    char chr;

    /* Determine the number of sentences */
    input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (input_file == NULL) {
        printf("failed to open file");
    }

    chr = fgetc(input_file);
    while (chr != EOF) {
        switch (chr) {
        case '.':
        case '!':
        case '?': {
            sentences_num++;
            break;
        }}
        chr = fgetc(input_file);
    }
    fclose(input_file);

    /* Copy everything ignoring the last 2 sentences */
    input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    output_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    chr = fgetc(input_file);
    while ((chr != EOF) && (sentences < (sentences_num - 2))) {
        switch (chr) {
        case '.':
        case '!':
        case '?': {
            sentences++;
            break;
        }}
        fputc(chr, output_file);
        chr = fgetc(input_file);
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);
}
```